# 2004 Toyota Corolla does not start with key

Tags: toyota, starting, corolla, key, remote-start

For more than ten days, I can not start my car with the key. It does start without problems with the remote starter. So, I think the problem is with the ignition switch. One more thing, the key turns but there are no sounds.

Comment: I think neimann was an autocorrect of ignition please fix if I'm wrong.

Comment: Thank you for the edit. I found this video using the keyword (ignition starter) you gave me: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DpkDW2zUCms. I will try to do the troubleshooting during the week and report the results.